# Not sure where i'm going wrong with my NoSQL query

Tags: mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I've tried searching for an answer for a while and came up blank. This is my first time on this site so excuse me for wording this question poorly. I'm trying write a NoSQL query to solve this problem:

**Identify the product with highest sales in terms of quantity and revenue.**

I tried using:

1.

```
    db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {product: '$name_field', quantity: 
    '$quantity_field', revenue:{$multiply:["$quantity_field", "$price_field"]}}}, 
    {$sort: {revenue: -1}}]);
```

I get something similar to this:

2.

```
   { _id: ObjectId("633dcf127e6d8005365d4454"),
    product: 'Classic Cars',
    quantity: 47,
    revenue: 9571.08 }
   { _id: ObjectId("633dcf127e6d8005365d447b"),
    product: 'Motorcycles',
    quantity: 49,
    revenue: 9394.28 }
   { _id: ObjectId("633dcf127e6d8005365d41b6"),
    product: 'Classic Cars',
    quantity: 46,
    revenue: 8889.5 }
```

When I try adding a limit to get first result of the sort (highest revenue)

3.

```
    db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {product: '$name_field', quantity: 
    '$quantity_field', revenue:{$multiply:["$quantity_field", "$price_field"]}}}, 
    {$sort: {revenue: -1}}, {$limit: 1}]);
```

I get a strange answer like below

4.

```
    { _id: ObjectId("633dcf127e6d8005365d40c0"),
    product: 'Vintage Cars',
    quantity: 30,
    revenue: 4080 }
```

Without the limit it returns the correct values of revenue for each document in descending order. With the limit, i'm not sure what is happening. I'm not too well versed in NoSQL yet. How do I return the single highest revenue from that sorted projection? Or if I'm using the wrong query, what is the correct query to solve the problem above?

Comment: Hmm this looks odd.  Where are you running this query? What versions of the database and client are you using?  Can you create and share an example on mongoplayground.net?

Comment: Why not just sort by both Quantity and Revenue descending?